# How to replace string from previous line using \r (Python)

Tags: python, string, replace, countdown

I'm attempting to make a countdown timer starting from 60 seconds. My only problem is that when I run the function, the program prints the code like so:

60

59

58

... etc

How would I go about replacing the 60 from that first line and put the 59 in it's place without printing 60 lines?

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import sys, time 

def countdown():
    seconds = 60
    while seconds >= 0:
        print seconds
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1
```

Comment: Careful with those tags! r is a reference to a language, not /r

Comment: @Conduit My apologies. Wasn't paying attention to the tags when adding them.

Comment: @Quadufu No worries - learning how to use SO takes a bit of time. Stick with it though! This is one of the best programming resources on the web, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print an empty line at the beginning of your `countdown` function. This will create the line needed for `\r` to work. Now, replace the `print seconds` part with

```
sys.stdout.write('\r  \r')
sys.stdout.write(str(seconds))
```

The first line clears the previous, empty line printed at the beginning of the function. The second one outputs the seconds.

The code:

```
def countdown():
    seconds = 60
    print ''
    while seconds >= 0:
        sys.stdout.write('\r  \r')
        sys.stdout.write(str(seconds))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1
```

Comment: This worked. However, I don't fully understand why. What does the sys.stdout.write() function do?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write` does the same thing as `print`, but it doesn't implicitly add `'\n'` at the end. That's what was messing up your earlier attempts.