# Print countdown when current digit replace the previous digit in the same place

Tags: python, formatting

I read:

[How to replace string from previous line using \r (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752932/how-to-replace-string-from-previous-line-using-r-python)

[How do I write output in same place on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517127/how-do-i-write-output-in-same-place-on-the-console)

However, I tried using all of the suggested solutions in the above link, but Eclipse insists to print each second in different line!

What am I missing? Is it a problem with Eclipse console?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

[How to get carriage return without line feed effect in Eclipse console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792478/how-to-get-carriage-return-without-line-feed-effect-in-eclipse-console)

This is a bug in eclipse console reported a decade ago!